# Eclipse android ID cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have this code:

```
        public void run() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                // This action will have the side-effect of blurring the currently focused element
                inAppWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + finalScriptToInject);
            }
```

But the id KITKAT gets the error: KITKAT cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: check the import of `Build`. it has to be `android.os.Build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT

As in docs : *October 2013: Android 4.4, KitKat, another tasty treat.*

means `KITKAT` constant added in *API level 19*.

So change current project target version to API level 19(Android 4.4)